# Replace image_picker functionality with file_picker to pick multiple images

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyotJ.png)

I have a simple flutter app that lets the user select a single image and upload it to firebase storage and then show it on the home screen of the app. Right now *[image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/example)* has been used in this app which lets it pick one image at a time. But I want to use *[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)* plugin to pick multiple images at once and upload them on the firebase storage.

I think the right way to do this would be to store the path of images in a list while selecting and then upload it. However, I have tried it multiple times but I am not able to make that work!
Any help is warmly welcomed!

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize a new Firebase App instance
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  // Select and image from the gallery or take a picture with the camera
  // Then upload to Firebase Storage
  Future<void> _upload(String inputSource) async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile? pickedImage;
    try {
      pickedImage = await picker.getImage(
          source: inputSource == 'camera'
              ? ImageSource.camera
              : ImageSource.gallery,
          maxWidth: 1920);

      final String fileName = path.basename(pickedImage!.path);
      File imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);

      try {
        // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
        await storage.ref(fileName).putFile(
            imageFile,
            SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
              'uploaded_by': 'A bad guy',
              'description': 'Some description...'
            }));

        // Refresh the UI
        setState(() {});
      } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  // Retriew the uploaded images
  // This function is called when the app launches for the first time or when an image is uploaded or deleted
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _loadImages() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];

    final ListResult result = await storage.ref().list();
    final List<Reference> allFiles = result.items;

    await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
      final String fileUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
      final FullMetadata fileMeta = await file.getMetadata();
      files.add({
        "url": fileUrl,
        "path": file.fullPath,
        "uploaded_by": fileMeta.customMetadata?['uploaded_by'] ?? 'Nobody',
        "description":
            fileMeta.customMetadata?['description'] ?? 'No description'
      });
    });

    return files;
  }

  // Delete the selected image
  // This function is called when a trash icon is pressed
  Future<void> _delete(String ref) async {
    await storage.ref(ref).delete();
    // Rebuild the UI
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kindacode.com'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () => _upload('camera'),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                    label: Text('camera')),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () => _upload('gallery'),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.library_add),
                    label: Text('Gallery')),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _loadImages(),
                builder: (context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final Map<String, dynamic> image =
                            snapshot.data![index];

                        return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            dense: false,
                            leading: Image.network(image['url']),
                            title: Text(image['uploaded_by']),
                            subtitle: Text(image['description']),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => _delete(image['path']),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Quote: final pickedFileList = await _picker.pickMultiImage(

Comment: i already tried this but i can't figure out the arguments

Comment: Then why didnt you ask instead of suggesting that there was no multiple aelect?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/changelog#081

The new release of **image_picker** does have a functionality to pick multiple images at a time on **IOS** and **Android**.

> 0.8.1
> Add a new method getMultiImage to allow picking multiple images on iOS 14 or higher and Android 4.3 or higher. Returns only 1 image
> for lower versions of iOS and Android.